# Basic LINQ query to SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, db4o

I have this LINQ query in C# for querying a db4o database.

```
IEnumerable<internetRecord> searchResult = from internetRecord ie in database
                                           where ie.GSrecordID.Contains(txtSearchString.Text)
                                           select ie;
```

What would be the equivalent query in SQL? (needed for comparison purposes) I have not worked with SQL much in the past and looking at it after using LINQ for a while it seems confusing.

Comment: [SQL: LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

Comment: If you ever want to see what queries get run then you can use SQL profiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE GSRecordID LIKE '%txtSearchString%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from internetrecord where GSrecordID like '%your comparison string%'
```

Provided internetrecord is your SQL table GSrecordID is the column of your table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about db40 but in standard SQL it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM internetRecord 
WHERE GSrecordID LIKE '%txtSearchString%'
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do something like this

```
var result = database.Where(x => x.GSrecordID.Contains(txtSearchString.Text));
```